# Python: Is there a way to split a string of numbers into every 3rd number?

Tags: python, list

For example, if I have a string a=123456789876567543 could i have a list like...

123
456
789
876
567
543

Comment: What do you want for "12345": "123 45" or "12 345"?
You might want to address that in your question.

Comment: I think you didn't understand Hans' request for clarification. If the length of the input isn't an integer multiple of three, you will have a group that is smaller than three digits, and then you must choose where it should appear.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many nearly-identical questions.

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> a="123456789"
>>> [int(a[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
[123, 456, 789]
```

Answer (score 6):

Recipe from the [itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) (you can define a fillvalue when the length is not a multiple of 3):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

s = '123456789876567543'

print [''.join(l) for l in grouper(3, s, '')]


>>> ['123', '456', '789', '876', '567', '543']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import re
>>> a = '123456789876567543'
>>> l = re.findall('.{1,3}', a)
>>> l
['123', '456', '789', '876', '567', '543']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = str(123456789876567543)
l = []
for i in xrange(0, len(s), 3):
    l.append(int(s[i:i+3]))
print l
```

Comment: Doesn't that fail if the length is not a multiple of 3?

Comment: No, it won't, string slices simply return shorter substrings if there are not enough characters.

Comment: I know it will fail if it isn't a multiple of 3. But for what I'm doing, it won't. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want right alignment:

```
a='123456789876567543'
format(int(a),',').split(',')
['123', '456', '789', '876', '567', '543']
a='12345'
format(int(a),',').split(',')
['12', '345']
```