# Right split a string into groups of 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the most **Pythonic** way to right split into groups of threes? I've seen this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2801117/1461607 but I need it to be right aligned. Preferably a simple efficient one-liner without imports.

- '123456789' = ['123','456','789']
- '12345678' = ['12','345','678']
- '1234567' = ['1','234','567']

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another way, not sure about efficiency (it'd be better if they were already numbers instead of strings), but is another way of doing it in 2.7+.

```
for i in map(int, ['123456789', '12345678', '1234567']):
    print i, '->', format(i, ',').split(',')

#123456789 -> ['123', '456', '789']
#12345678 -> ['12', '345', '678']
#1234567 -> ['1', '234', '567']
```

Comment: eh? I can't see where the 'groups of three' bit comes into this.

Comment: @user1461607 not sure what you mean but `format(num, ',')` formats a string into conventional `,` delimited blocks of 3, so that splitting on `,` gives you the required result.

Comment: @user1461607 it's a useful feature for formatting numbers (as it's quite common)... so you could one liner it to be `format(int('1234567'), ',').split(',')` if you wanted...

Comment: clever solution :-) I wonder how it compares to mine performance wise

Comment: @FabianHenze The thing is that the format/split approach is utilising the underlying implementation to do the "dirty work" - so will be faster... The bottleneck comes with the converting the string to an integer first for the formatting to work...

Answer (score 6):

simple (iterated from the answer in your link):

`[int(a[::-1][i:i+3][::-1]) for i in range(0, len(a), 3)][::-1]`

Explanation : `a[::-1]` is the reverse list of `a`
We will compose the inversion with the slicing.

### Step one : reverse the list

```
 a           =   a[::-1]
'123456789' - > '987654321'
```

### Step Two : Slice in parts of three's

```
 a[i]           =   a[i:i+3]
 '987654321'    ->  '987','654','321'
```

### Step Three : invert the list again to present the digits in increasing order

```
 a[i]           =  int(a[i][::-1])
 '987','654','321' -> 789, 654, 123
```

### Final Step : invert the whole list

```
 a           =   a[::-1]
 789, 456, 123 -> 123, 456, 789
```

### Bonus : Functional synthetic sugar

It's easier to debug when you have proper names for functions

```
invert = lambda a: a[::-1]
slice  = lambda array, step : [ int( invert( array[i:i+step]) ) for i in range(len(array),step)  ]

answer = lambda x: invert ( slice ( invert (x) , 3 ) )
answer('123456789')
#>> [123,456,789]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` for `a = '123456789'`.

Answer (score 5):

This is the best I came up with:

```
[a[max(i-3,0):i] for i in range(len(a), 0, -3)][::-1]
```

and another one, which works without inverting the list, but is *slightly* more ugly:

```
[a[max(0,i):i+3] for i in range((len(a)-1)%3-2, len(a), 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest isn't always the most Pythonic.

```
def by3(s):
    out = []
    while len(s):
        out.insert(0, s[-3:])
        s = s[:-3]
    return out
```

```
>>> by3(a)
['12', '345', '678']
```

Answer (score 1):

A four liner:

```
splitted_number = []
while number:
    number, r = number[:-3], number[-3:]
    splitted_number.insert(0, r)
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2cents if someone find this usefull: `textwrap` is built-in module that do the thing.

```
from textwrap import wrap

a = '123456789'
b = wrap(a, 3)
>>> b ['123', '456', '789']
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding @Manu answer,

```
from textwrap import wrap

a = '123456789'
b = wrap(a, 3)
print(b)

newlist = []

for i in b:
    newlist.append(int(i))
   
print(newlist)
```

```
['123', '456', '789']
[123, 456, 789]

[Program finished]
```

or

```
n = 1234567890
v = [] 
while n > 0:
    n, r = divmod(n, 1000) 
    v.insert(0, r)

print(v)
```

```
[1, 234, 567, 890]

[Program finished]
```